# Persist LinkedHashMap in blob

Tags: spring, hibernate, blob

I'm trying to persist a LinkedHashMap in a blob field of my db.

My entity looks as follows

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private long timestamp;
    @Lob
    private Map<String, Object> payload;
...
```

My repository looks as follows

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
}
```

When trying to store my Event object I get the following error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

Any clues about what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more annotation to the mapping:

```
    @Lob
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "key_column")
    @Column(name = "value_column")
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Object> payload;
```

This is the needed setup, where the map is defined as  `Map<Basic, Basic>`

Answer (score 2):

`BLOB` is used for storing binary data, `BLOB` values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

I'll suggest that you use `TEXT` instead.
And also you must use `JPA @EntityListeners or Callbacks Methods @PrePersist: and @PostLoad` your code become

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private long timestamp;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String payload

    @Transient
    private Map<String, Object> payloadOb;

    @PrePersist
    public payloadMapToText(){
      this.payload = mapToString(this.payloadOb);
    }

   @PostLoad
    public payloadTextToMap(){
      this.payloadOb = stringToMap(this.payload);
    }

}
```